# error in running differetial_drive package

Tags: ros, python, differential-drive, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I want to use a package named differential_drive which is written as a base_controller for two differential wheeled robot by Jon Stephan.

As i can not install it by source from my zone, i downloded its zip and extract it to my directory. This package consists of some python files and after compiling no node has been constructed. I think .py files are my nodes and i should use them in the launch file as below:

> ```
> <launch>
> ```

```
  <node pkg="differential_drive" type="pid_velocity.py" name="lpid_velocity">
       <remap from="wheel" to="lwheel"/>
       <remap from="motor_cmd" to="lmotor_cmd"/>
       <remap from="wheel_vtarget" to="lwheel_vtarget"/>
       <remap from="wheel_vel" to="lwheel_vel"/>
       <rosparam param="Kp">200</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="Ki">200</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="Kd">0</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="out_min">-255</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="out_max">255</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="rate">30</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="timeout_ticks">4</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="rolling_pts">5</rosparam>
  </node>
  <node pkg="differential_drive" type="pid_velocity.py" name="rpid_velocity">
       <remap from="wheel" to="rwheel"/>
       <remap from="motor_cmd" to="rmotor_cmd"/>
       <remap from="wheel_vtarget" to="rwheel_vtarget"/>
       <remap from="wheel_vel" to="rwheel_vel"/>
       <rosparam param="Kp">200</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="Ki">200</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="Kd">0</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="out_min">-255</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="out_max">255</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="rate">30</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="timeout_ticks">4</rosparam>
       <rosparam param="rolling_pts">5</rosparam>
  </node>
  <node pkg="differential_drive" type="virtual_joystick.py" name="virtual_joystick" output="screen"/>
  <node pkg="differential_drive" type="twist_to_motors.py" name="twist_to_motors" output="screen">
      <rosparam param="base_width">0.32</rosparam>
 </node>
</launch>
```

But when i run my launch file, ROS can not find nodes and i see these errors:

> ```
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [differential_drive/pid_velocity.py]: can't locate node [pid_velocity.py] in package [differential_drive]
> ```

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [differential_drive/pid_velocity.py]: can't locate node [pid_velocity.py] in package [differential_drive]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [differential_drive/virtual_joystick.py]: can't locate node [virtual_joystick.py] in package [differential_drive]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [differential_drive/twist_to_motors.py]: can't locate node [twist_to_motors.py] in package [differential_drive]
```

Is it because i just extract zip files to my directory? I mean should i use another command to locate this nodes in package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199458/error-in-running-differetial_drive-package/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're looking at the wiki of [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive), its source repository is git so I first cloned it:

```
$ git clone https://jfstepha@code.google.com/p/differential-drive
$ mv differential-drive differential_drive
```

Clearly the folder name and the package name doesn't align so I renamed it.

Then put this directory into somewhere that's included in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Then you should be able to eg. `rosrun differential_drive twist_to_motors.py`.

You didn't mention where and how you got a zip file, but as long as the content isn't "broken", above should work with your zip.

Update:

> rosrun and one of the nodes, i see an error which says this file is not a executable.

Make sure the python files are executable. Try, for example:

```
chmod 755 `rospack find differential_drive`/nodes/twist_to_motors.py
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-12-14**:
if you look at wiki link, it does not exist. But the true link is [https://code.google.com/p/differential-drive](http://code.google.com/p/differential-drive). Because i can not access to its source from linux terminal in my country, i just could downloded it zip file from this link.

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-12-14**:
if i want to use rosrun and one of the nodes, i see an error which says this file is not a executable.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-14**:
I'm sorry that I have no idea what's going on with your internet connectivity, but sounds like at least you were able to download the source, which is enough.

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-12-14**:
Thanks a lot, the problem solved by the last command in your answer.